# C++ / OpenGL - 2D - How to clip a circle in a rectangle boundary box

Tags: c++, opengl

I was just wondering how would I go about clipping a circle in a rectangular boundary box? I am currently using the Cohen–Sutherland algorithm for line clipping in my program and so far I've managed to get rectangles and polygons to clip. However, for circle clipping, I have no idea how I would accomplish this. I'm using the following to construct my circle:

```
glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
double radius = 50;  
for(int angle = 0; angle <= 360; angle++ ){
    float const curve = 2 * PI * (float)angle / (float)360;
    glVertex2f(point.x + sin(curve) * radius, point.y + cos(curve) * radius);
}
glEnd();
```

My clipping algorithm is the same as the one here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohen%E2%80%93Sutherland_algorithm. However, it returns 2 points representing a new line to later be used to draw the clipped shape. So basically I've tried to do this:

```
line Lines[360] // an array with size 360 with data type line, which is a struct holding two points (x1, y1, x2, y2) of the new line returned by my clipping function.

double radius = 50;
for(int angle = 0; angle < 360; angle++){
    float const currentCurve = 2 * PI * (float)angle / (float)360;
    float const nextCurve = 2 * PI * (float)(angle+1) / (float)360;
    int x1 = (int)(point[i].x + sin(currentCurve) * radius); // point is another struct holding only a single point. 
    y1 = (int)(point[i].y + cos(currentCurve) * radius);
    x2 = (int)(point[i+1].x+ sin(nextCurve) * radius);
    y2 = (int)(point[i+1].y + cos(nextCurve) * radius);=
    // Clip the points with the clipping algorithm:
    Lines[i] = Clipper(x1, y1, x2, y2);
}

// Once all lines have been clipped or not, draw:

glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
for(int i = 0; i < 360; i++){
    glVertex2f(Lines[i].x1, Lines[i].y1);
    glVertex2f(Lines[i].x2, Lines[i].y2);
}
glEnd();
```

Note that, I've drawn a circle on the screen with a mouse and and stored each 360 points into a struct array called point, which is apart of a linked list. So I have like 1 node representing one circle on the screen.

Anyway, with the above, my circle is not drawing clipped (or drawing at all for that matter) and my application crashes after a few mouse clicks.

Comment: Your using the variable i to index the array Lines, but actually I think you should be using the variable "angle", in the above for loop.  I'm not too sure what your clipper returns if the line is completely outside of the rectangle.  In this case you shouldn't draw the line at all.

Answer (score 0):

Use the scissor test - read up on glScissor(): http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glScissor.xml